# Ubuntu 16.04.3, Google chrome plays very little sound

Tags: sound, google-chrome, browser

Google chrome version: Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I've tried uninstall and reinstall google chrome, but the problem remains.Other browsers (firefox, Chromium web browser) are normal, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, fixed this issue, in sound setting.

[image: Ubuntu sound setting]